# Unique Web Page Url after every transaction

Tags: javascript, php

I need a small help here. I am building a book business website. here, when the customer wants to download the book, first he has to pay the bill and then after the successful payment, the page redirects to the download page where the customer can download that book. Here my question is how to create a unique web page address(for example : if the 1st customer pays the bill then the download page appears say (ex:www.downloadthebook.com/1) and if the 2nd customer pays the bill then the download page has to appear like this, say (www.downloadthebook.com/2). and also if the customer copy the url of that download page and loads in the new tab. the url should not work. The download page only works if the payment is succesfull with a new unique url page . Please help me...

Comment: not possible to help unless you show what you have tried

Comment: i am creating the website with html and javascript. and also am a beginner. help me

Comment: These are called one-time or one-use download link. You can generate links with, for example, a hash function, store that in the database, and when it's accessed you mark it as such and don't allow accessing it afterwards. If you want to hide the URL behind the user session/account that completed the checkout, just do extra validation upon accessing of the URL.

Comment: url hashing is the way

Comment: You're probably going to spend a lot of time as a beginner. I hope you're not underestimating it. However, it's an investment because you'll learn a lot. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with database concept. Like when customer1 is paying then save order data in table with payment `success(payment transaction id)`. Table must have status by names `is_doenloaded(ENUM filed value y/n)` And Download book page will common for all user there you need to identify user from that custom table and also you need to rectify for which book customer has paid. Once he downloaded just just update the status of the field by Y .  so he will not be able to download further.

Hope my idea will helps you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is similliar to a "profile" page, Like
I got in my website http://domain/profile/someonesUsername
To do this, I use HTACCESS,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)$ ?bookid=$1 [NC,L]
```

And then inside the PHP, You'll need this:

```
else if(isset($_GET["bookid"]))
    {
        $bookid = $_GET["bookid"];
        if(/*Here you can check if the customer bought*/ == 1)
        { // If he has,
            header("Location: http://domain/download/book.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            die("You didn't purchase this book!");
        }
    }
```